# Importing a MaterialUI theme from another file correctly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hi I'm new to MaterialUI and React. I'm trying to import a theme from another file and change it using a switch in MaterialUI. I've created a Layout component and will include this directly in the App.

It works perfectly fine when the themes are defined within the same file where they are required. Like below.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Grid, Paper, Card, Switch, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { ThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

function Layout() {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);

  const darkTheme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      type: "dark",
    },
  });

  const lightTheme = createMuiTheme({});

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkMode ? darkTheme : lightTheme}>
      <Paper style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
        <Grid container direction="column">
          <Switch checked={darkMode} onChange={() => setDarkMode(!darkMode)} />
          <Typography variant="h1">Home</Typography>
          <Card>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo
            temporibus eum iure aperiam quisquam obcaecati nesciunt inventore
            laudantium, ut, cumque ullam. Dolore itaque eum molestiae, dolor
            laborum iure quisquam cum.
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

But when I move the themes to separate files, the mode is changed on the first time I click the Switch. But then it will remain unchanged no matter how much I click the Switch again. The related codes are below.
In the `Layout.jsx` file:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Grid, Paper, Card, Switch, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

//Import themes
import darkTheme from "../Themes/DarkTheme";
import lightTheme from "../Themes/LightTheme";

function Layout() {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkMode ? darkTheme : lightTheme}>
      <Paper style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
        <Grid container direction="column">
          <Switch checked={darkMode} onChange={() => setDarkMode(!darkMode)} />
          <Typography variant="h1">Home</Typography>
          <Card>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo
            temporibus eum iure aperiam quisquam obcaecati nesciunt inventore
            laudantium, ut, cumque ullam. Dolore itaque eum molestiae, dolor
            laborum iure quisquam cum.
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

In the `DarkTheme.js` file:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const darkTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark",
  },
});

export default darkTheme;
```

In the `LightTheme.js` file:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const lightTheme = createMuiTheme({});

export default lightTheme;
```

Would be a great help if anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why that doesn't work but I can show you a way you can have the themes in a separate file and import them in, and the toggle/switch will work.

In your `DarkTheme.js` and `LightTheme.js`, remove `createMuiTheme` and export just the theme object, which we will pass into `createMuiTheme` in `Layout.jsx`. So they will look like this:

`DarkTheme.js`:

```
const darkTheme = {
  palette: {
    type: "dark",
  },
};

export default darkTheme;
```

`LightTheme.js`:

```
const lightTheme = {
  palette: {
    type: "light"
  }
};

export default lightTheme;
```

In your `Layout.jsx`, import `createMuiTheme` from `@material-ui/core/styles` and assign a `theme` variable equal to `createMuiTheme` with either the `darkTheme` or `lightTheme` object passed it as an argument depending on whether `darkMode` is true. Then, assign this `theme` variable to the `theme` prop in `ThemeProvider`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Grid, Paper, Card, Switch, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

//Import themes
import darkTheme from "../Themes/DarkTheme";
import lightTheme from "../Themes/LightTheme";

function Layout() {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);

  let theme = darkMode ? createMuiTheme(darkTheme) : createMuiTheme(lightTheme);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Paper style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
        <Grid container direction="column">
          <Switch checked={darkMode} onChange={() => setDarkMode(!darkMode)} />
          <Typography variant="h1">Home</Typography>
          <Card>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo
            temporibus eum iure aperiam quisquam obcaecati nesciunt inventore
            laudantium, ut, cumque ullam. Dolore itaque eum molestiae, dolor
            laborum iure quisquam cum.
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

**Side Note**

If you want your theme to apply for the whole application, normally it is best practice your upper most parent in your app which is usually in `App.jsx`. This ensures all the children (i.e. every single component) will have access to the theme. Or if `Layout` is intended to be the parent container, then it should accept a `children` prop, so that all children can access the theme. I've shown both cases below.

```
// App.jsx

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      // insert component here
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
// Layout.jsx
function Layout({ children }) {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);

  let theme = = darkMode ? createMuiTheme(darkTheme) : createMuiTheme(lightTheme);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Paper style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
        <Grid container direction="column">
          <Switch checked={darkMode} onChange={() => setDarkMode(!darkMode)} />
            { children }
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

// App.jsx

import Layout from "../components/Layout";

function App() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      // insert component here
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default App;
```